# Best way to inject server-side variables/function results into CSS under ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, css

My ASP.NET app has some server-side methods whose results I'd like to inject into my CSS files. For example, rather than hard-code the URL to a logo, I might like to insert a call to MyHelperClass.GetCurrentLogoUrl() in the middle of the CSS file.

If I were writing an ASPX page, I could use [code render blocks x](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z.aspx) (that is, stuff like "<%=MyHelperClass.GetCurrentLogoUrl()%>") in the middle of my HTML markup. It would be nice to do something similar for CSS.

There are some CSS preprocessing frameworks, e.g. dotless, and they seem to have some cool features, but I'm not aware of any of them supporting making C# calls like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just make an aspx page and link to it when including a stylesheet. You'll miss out on css highlighting though.

```
<link href="http://domain.com/css.aspx" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This has the potential to generate unnecessary overhead though, especially if most properties you're modifying do not change at runtime. In that case you may want to research [TT files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) which basically generate other files when deployed - in your case, you could have it generate the css with whatever complex logic.

Comment: I like this, offering both a runtime solution and a deploy-time solution. About the only other thing one might wish for advice on is whether it's possible to integrate either of these techniques with CSS preprocessors like DotLess! (But one suspects you could extend your answers for that -- e.g. have a build process that uses TT files to generate .less files, which in turn generate CSS files.)

Comment: @Chris: yes, chaining them sounds doable. I don't have experience with DotLess, but instead I use "Mindscape Web Workbench" VS extension - basically you make a .sass file and it generates a processed css every time you save it. That being said, I was unable to set up chaining for this scenario (i.e. use .tt to generate .sass to generate .css) but I'm writing this off as an extension oversight!

Answer (score 2):

[David P's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/274425) to [ASP.NET MVC URL auto-resolution in CSS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240394/asp-net-mvc-url-auto-resolution-in-css-files) suggests one approach. If you give your CSS files the .aspx extension and then use a Page directive to tell ASP.NET that it's actually a CSS file, like so

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ContentType="text/css" %>
```

then you can write CSS, but also use the normal ASP.NET code render blocks. It feels a little bizarre to name CSS files .aspx, but an initial test suggests this could work.

**UPDATE**: Props to o.v. for pointing this out even faster than me.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject a classname into the html, something like:

```
<input type="text" id="myTextBox" cssClass="<%=myClassName%>" />
```

You can also change the class name in the code behind using the .attributes method.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following into your `<head></head>` section of your page

```
<style runat="server" id="cssPhoneResize" type="text/css"></style>
```

Then from your server-side method:

```
string logoUrl = "/images/logo2.jpg";
cssPhoneResize.InnerHtml += "#Image{-image: url(" + logoUrl + ");}";
```

Hope this helps!